# Threading, ConcurrencyMode and UseSynchronizationContext clarification

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, wcf

I have WCF service running in a WPF application.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

This WCF is logging service meaning no multithreading issues, all calls should be fast and no reply (client has IsOneWay and binding is NetNamedPipes).

From what I understand:

**InstanceContextMode.Single** - Means this class in singleton, there is only 1 instance of it. and all calls reaches this class.
**ConcurrencyMode.Multiple** - Each call to this service, will be in new/different thread.

When i set these 2 settings, All calls are made from the GUI Thread, Only after I added **UseSynchronizationContext = false** - the calls invoked from other threads.

My question is - If i dont want to log via the GUI thread, Why do I need to define both ConcurrencyMode and UseSynchContext ? Am I missing something usingthis settings ? Why ConcurrencyMode is not enough (because its wpf application ?)

Thanks